# How to Covert to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, embedded-linux, zeromq

I am working on a large scale embedded system built using Python and we are using ZeroMQ to make everything modular.  I have sensor data being sent across a ZeroMQ serial port in the form of the python Dictionary as shown here:

```
accel_com.publish_message({"ACL_X": ACL_1_X_val})
```

Where accel_com is a Communicator class we built that wraps the ZeroMQ logic that publishes messages across a port. Here you can see we are sending Dictionaries across.
However, on the other side of the communication port, I have another module that grabs this data using this code:

```
accel_msg = san.get_last_message("sensor/accelerometer")
accel.ax = accel_msg.get('ACL_X')
accel.ay = accel_msg.get('ACL_Y')
accel.az = accel_msg.get('ACL_Z')
```

The problem is when I try to treat accel_msg as a Python Dictionary, I get an Error:

```
'NoneType' object does not have a method 'get()'.
```

So my guess is the dictionary is not going across the wire correctly. I am not very familiar with Python so I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: The error message is saying `accel_msg` returned `None`. as in, no data at all

Comment: Not terribly familiar with ZeroMQ, but what happens if you call `accel_msg.get('ACL_Y')` on a message without an `ACL_Y` field? Would that return `None`?

Comment: but now if I print out `accel_msg` by itself, then it will print out this: `{'timestamp': 1391630244.242758, 'message_number': 9285, 'ACL_Z': -267, 'module_name': 'sensor/accelerometer'}`

Comment: i suspect you are in some loop ... that error is being thrown when you get none I think ... put it in a try/except where you print it(`accel_msg`) on exception

Comment: @HughBothwell It simply gives me the same error telling me there is no get() method for NoneType...

Comment: @MattHintzke: "well then", that might be your problem?

Comment: ...But as you see from my previous comment, `accel_msg` DOES have a value when printed, I think the value is just a literal string though, so I need a way to convert a literal string to a dictionary..?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried that and the loop just went forever, never caught an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @JoranBeasley's comment:

`accel_msg` is *sometimes* `None`, such as while it's waiting for a message. The solution is to skip over `None` messages

```
while True:              # waiting indefinitely for messages
    accel_msg = san.get_last_message("sensor/accelerometer")
    if accel_msg:        # or more explicitly, if accel_msg is not None:
        accel.ax = accel_msg.get('ACL_X')
        accel.ay = accel_msg.get('ACL_Y')
        accel.az = accel_msg.get('ACL_Z')
        break            # if you only want one message. otherwise remove this
    else:
        print accel_msg  # which is almost certainly None
```

Comment: comments are just too short for explanations. sometimes you just have to *assume* you know the answer and post as such, prepared to delete if off base :)

Comment: Oh I see what Joran mean now. I didn't realize that there would be some messages that are Dictionaries and others that are None. Thanks!